# How to apply different page width for different pages in xsl? This is for generating PDF

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have to generate a pdf using xml and xsl.
On the PDF i need different width for different pages.
How can I achive this?

Thanks and Regards

Krishnan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete xsl-fo sample :

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">  
                <fo:layout-master-set>
                    <fo:simple-page-master page-height="10cm" page-width="5cm" 
                            master-name="format1">
                        <fo:region-body />
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                    <fo:simple-page-master page-height="5cm" page-width="10cm" 
                            master-name="format2">
                        <fo:region-body/>
                    </fo:simple-page-master>
                </fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="format1">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:block>Test format 1</fo:block>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
                <fo:page-sequence master-reference="format2">
                    <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                        <fo:block>Test format 2</fo:block>
                    </fo:flow>
                </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```